# Lead Function in Power BI

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Is there a `LEAD` function like in SQL in Power BI ?

I'm trying to find the next row value of a column to find the different of days row2 - row1.

Same like SQL LEAD AND LAG

Comment: Can you please share your input and expected output? Your model ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve LEAD/LAG using Power Query also.

1. Create an Index column starting from 1
2. Create LEAD/LAG columns using index from Index column
3. Finally replace errors with zero or any other default value you want

M Code:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjRSitWJVjI2AVOGZhAeRNAEImgKETQ3B1MWFkqxsQA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Value = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Value", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"xyz" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Lead", each #"Added Index"{[Index]}[#"Value"]),
    #"abc" = Table.AddColumn(xyz, "Lag", each #"Added Index"{[Index]-2}[#"Value"]),
    #"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(abc, {{"Lead", 0}, {"Lag", 0}})
in
    #"Replaced Errors"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [OFFSET](https://dax.guide/offset/) function.
e.g.

```
DEFINE
    MEASURE Sales[Prev Year Sales] =
        CALCULATE (
            [Sales Amount],
            OFFSET (
                1,
                ORDERBY ( 'Date'[Year], ASC )
            )
        )
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    'Date'[Year],
    TREATAS ( { 2019, 2020 }, 'Date'[Year] ),
    "Sales Amount", [Sales Amount],
    "Next Row Sales", [Prev Year Sales]
)
```

https://dax.do/nMjGnwnqKELUa2/

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
DEFINE
    MEASURE Sales[Prev Year Sales] =
        CALCULATE (
            MAX('Date'[Year]),
            OFFSET (
                1,
                ORDERBY ( 'Date'[Year], ASC )
            )
        )
EVALUATE
SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
    'Date'[Year],
    TREATAS ( { 2019, 2020 }, 'Date'[Year] ),
    "Sales Amount", [Sales Amount],
    "Next Row Sales", [Prev Year Sales]
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, understand a bit but confused  sorry,                                                         
10/06/2023 07:15:22 AM 07/06/2023 10:36:32 AM
07/06/2023 10:36:32 AM                                                                                                       want it like this as shown above, will do the calculation later using DateDiff function

Comment: yet to try it, will get back to you if im still not able to get it, the data I have is not clean, need to clean it and get the correct row value in order

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no LEAD and LAG function in Power BI. But you can simply emulate it in Power Query M using tow indexes and a self join.

The steps are as follows:

1. Sort rows by partition and order by columns
2. Add two Index Columns with different start values for the LAG/LEAD offset
3. Self-Join the table with itself using these indexes
4. Retrieve required columns from the joined row.
5. Calculate the result

I have summarized the detailed procedure in a post on Medium:

https://medium.com/microsoft-power-bi/a-super-fast-method-for-calculating-lag-and-lead-in-power-bi-9d99be97d085